# Simple coding I still can't figure out

Tags: c++

While using C++, how would one spam the RMB 5 times when the RMB is pressed once. Sorry for my lack of skill and knowledge :/ I would assume a loop but that wouldn't help, for it would stop when the key isn't being pressed. Or could you set the interval in which it jumps to be 5, would that do what i ask?

```
 if (keyinfo.keychar == '???' ) 
 for (int counter=0; counter<=5 ;counter=???)
```

RMB = Right Mouse Button

Comment: In the 1400+ pages that make up the current C++ standard, I am unable to find any mention of anything called "RMB". Need more coffee.

Comment: RMB = Right Mouse Button?

Comment: Misstyped, RMS=Richard M. Stallman?

Comment: RMB = Right Mouse Button

Comment: Did you mean "span"? Spamming the right mouse button (as I assume is what you meant by RMB) makes no sense

Comment: @AhmedAnwar: I think it Wiseguy is asking about a way to transform a single right mouse button click into 5.

Comment: @MikeMB is correct, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If what you're asking is how to execute a certain action 5 times whenever the right mouse button is clicked, then the following code will do that. For example, if you want to execute the action when the RMB is clicked on a label `label1`, this is how you can do it

```
    private void label1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                //Your code here
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @mikeMB its c# if im not mistaken, and ty very much for this <3

Comment: Yes, yes it's C# not C++ I apologize. My mistake

Comment: @Wiseguy2433 Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16485514/visual-c-detect-a-right-click-on-a-button

Comment: You're an immense help and I appreciate you greatly, truly astounding how 1 of the many would take their own time to help another who wants some help. By any chance do you have a thread such as the one you linked me that has dealings with spacebar? @Ahmed Anwar

Comment: You're welcome, it's my pleasure to help.
And what would you like to detect the spacebar on? Is it like reading a character from the console, and you'd like to check is that was a space?
If you mean that you'd like to check if he spacebar is pressed just randomly in a winforms application for example, I don't see how that could be done.
Anyways you can check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27937617/how-detect-spacebar

Comment: @ahmedAnwar In essence, I would like to make my spacebar click spacebar 5 times. 1 space = 5 clicks. I would like this for a project i have going for small game I've been working on, still can't seem to find an easier way to do such a simple action. I appreciate all your help!

Comment: Oh well then that will definitely depend on the platform that you're using to develop the game. And platoform (like Unity XNA which are the only two I worked with) will have some kind of triggers or listeners that detect when a key is pressed. You need to search for some kimd of tutorial for the platform that you're using

Comment: @ahmedanwar I'm trying to get/ create a script to spam this key 5 times is to check that it cannot be exploited by such a program, like a macro, or script.